# Neo4j - ORDER BY syntax error

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

This cipher query is throwing the syntax error when I am sorting the result on relationship property using ORDER BY clause.

My query:

```
$MATCH(a{word:"review"})-[co:coocr]->(b) RETURN co LIMIT 20 ORDER BY co.val DESC
```

Syntax Error report:

```
Invalid input 'R': expected 'p/P' (line 4, column 2 (offset: 60))
"ORDER BY co.val DESC"
  ^
```

where the relationship co exists a property like **"val:0.66"** where value is a double valued number.

Please some one suggest where I am missing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reverse the order of the `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` clauses:

```
MATCH (a{word:"review"})-[co:coocr]->(b)RETURN co ORDER BY co.val DESC LIMIT 20;
```